# Jquery- Find the element has given style property

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a html table

```
    <table class="mytable">
       <tr>
           <td>
            test value
           </td>
       <tr>
    </table>
```

on loading the page dynamically adding a td

```
        $(".mytable tr:first").append("<td id='scheduledInMyLearnStatus' class='changeFieldValue' style='background-color:#FE2E2E;'></td>");
```

now on clicking the that particular td i want to compare whether its has backgroung color =#FE2E2E
or has anything else

```
    $('td').live('click', function() {

       //compare here 
    });
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/css/ - Used to get the value of a css property. Give it a try :) e.g. $(element).css('background-color')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jQuery `css()` method, please note that `live()` is deprecated you can use `on` instead:

```
$(document).on('click', '#scheduledInMyLearnStatus', function(){ // or $('.mytable').on
    if($(this).css('background-color') == "rgb(254, 46, 46)") {
      // do something
    }
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w45S9/)

Comment: Since `.myTable` is static, you replace `document` with `'.myTable'` for better performance. (+1)

Comment: why to compare with rgb value ?
can i compare something like if($(this).css('background-color') == "#FE2E2E") {
      // do something

Comment: @monda unfortunately no, `css()` returns a rgb value.

Comment: How to get the rgb value of a colour.. i need to compare with more colors?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use just one selector:

```
$(document).on("click", ".changeFieldValue[style~='background-color']", function () {
  // do something
});
```

And if u need the determined color, 'background-color: rgb(200, 122, 122)' instead of just 'background-color'.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your function look like

$('.mytable td').live('click', function()
{

```
        bgColor= hexc($(this).css("background-color"));
        if(bgColor.toUpperCase() == "#FE2E2E")
        {
            alert("Background color matched to '#FE2E2E'")
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Background color don't  matched to '#FE2E2E'")
        }

    });
```

and Defination for hexc will be

function hexc(colorval)

```
{
    var color = "";
    var parts = colorval.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
    if(parts != null )
    {
        parts[0] = "#";
        for (var i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) 
        {
            parts[i] = parseInt(parts[i]).toString(16);
            if (parts[i].length == 1) parts[i] = '0' + parts[i];
        }
        color = parts.join('');
    }
    return color;
}
```